# How to find the point where the error occurs in optim function

Tags: r, optimization

My understanding of 'optim' function is that it randomly or by some algorithm tries to evaluate the function at many points and find a parameter value that the evaluated value is minimized.

Optim produces an error message if the evaluated value is +/- infinity, but I can't find where this error occurs. That is, I would like to know the exact value of the parameter that the function becomes +/- infinity.
How can I do this?

Comment: `options(error=recover)` ...

Comment: @BenBolker  No, it does not give me the answer that I'm looking for

Comment: can you please give a reproducible example?  An alternative it to put `print()` or `cat()` statements in your objective function so you can see what's going on.